# How to check compatibility of installed programs before upgrading Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, lts

Ubuntu 20**.04** LTS is offering me an upgrade to 22**.04** LTS.

In that past, I have occasionally discovered too late that certain programs in the specific versions that I require are not supported / not available on the latest version of Ubuntu.

Is there any way to run a compatibility check on all installed programs to ensure they are available for latest greatest Ubuntu?

[Edit 25.08.2022: Added .04 to the version numbers for clarity}

Comment: There's no way to do that, per se. How could Ubuntu know what specific programs and versions you need? When you run the release upgrade, it will tell you beforehand if it plans to _remove_ any apps, and you can choose whether or not to permit it, but for checking versions of still-included apps, I think you'd be best off to just go to https://packages.ubuntu.com/ and check the versions available there.

Comment: @guiverc I was actually asking about LTS. Thank you, I didn't know there is a difference.

Comment: @Auspex >> "How could Ubuntu know what specific programs and versions you need?" Simply by checking the list of installed programs. If I have it installed,  the upgrader can safely assume I need it.

Comment: For clarification: A while back, I upgraded to the latest LTS on Raspberry Pi, just to discover that the version of Kodi I need for addon compatibility isn't available. Although this is just a minor nuisance, it taught me a lesson: You can't always expect programs to still be available after an upgrade. We also run Ubuntu LTS on laptops for business purposes and use programs like Teams and Skype, and if any of those programs were to quit working after an upgrade, it would be very bad. I want to proceed with caution, hence this question.

Comment: @guiverc Ah, I didn't know that. Thank you for clarifying, I have corrected the question.

Comment: Teams and Skype are commercial programs.  If you're worried about those, it's probably best to check on their respective homepages to see if they still support Linux/Ubuntu.  I don't think Canonical would do something purposely to lose compatibility with them, but they may choose to stop supporting Linux.  As for Canonical-based software, it has happened to me all the time.  Of course, it happens more often with less popular software.  You can also check packages.ubuntu.com to see if some of your popular programs still exist in 22.04.

Comment: Ray, it _does_ check the list of installed programs, and tells you if it is going to remove any that are no longer supported. It's up to you to decide if you want that to happen, but it _can't_ possibly tell what version you _need_ (unless you've apt-pinned a version, and I'm not sure whether it could _do_ the upgrade in that case). `Teams`, though, is not available from Canonical. Third party sources are _always_ disabled on upgrade, so it won't change them (but equally, you can't upgrade them later without editing your apt sources)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to test using a LiveUSB.

1. Create a 22.04 Install LiveUSB.
2. Boot from it. **DON'T install**, instead go into the "Try Ubuntu" environment.
3. Install the specific versions of your favorite applications into the "Try Ubuntu" environment.
    Do all your testing, make all your mistakes, and do your learning there.
4. When complete, poweroff your system, remove the USB, and reboot into your original and **untouched** older system.

An hour or two spent testing and taking notes is much better than days or weeks trying to cleanup a mess.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to upvote this, but thanks for this answer! This can also be done in a VirtualBox VM.

Comment: @RayCulp You could accept this answer, though, if you like it even if you can't upvote it, I think.